# wcf contract added properties got null values on the existing contract

Tags: wcf

```
namespace CQGlobal.BackOffice.Domain.RmsRepository
{
    using System;
    using CQGlobal.BackOffice.Domain.RmsModel;
    using CQGlobal.BackOffice.Service.Types;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using TmsModel = CQGlobal.BackOffice.Domain.TmsModel;
    using tmsTypes = CQGlobal.BackOffice.Domain.TmsTypes;

    public interface IRiskManagementRepository : IDisposable
    {
        void DataAffectedByPriceChange(List<Tb_ClosingPrice> prices);

        //void DataAffectedByPositionChangeByOrder(List<Tb_OrderImport> orders);

        //IEnumerable<string> DataAffectedByPositionChangeByOrder(List<Tb_OrderImport> orders, ref List<RMSSummary> summary);

        IEnumerable<string> ExecuteNewOrders(List<Tb_OrderImport> orders, bool simulate = false);

        IEnumerable<string> FetchRMSTopics(string search);

        IEnumerable<string> FetchRMSTopics(string search, string orderby="AcctNo", int page=0, int size=0);

        IEnumerable<RMSDisplay> FetchRMSSummary(string search);

        IEnumerable<RMSDisplay> FetchRMSSummary(string search, string orderby = "AcctNo", int page = 0, int size = 0);

        IEnumerable<RMSDisplay> FetchRMSSummaryByTopic(List<string> topics, long companyId);

        IEnumerable<string> InsertRiskManagementSummaryRemarks(Tb_RiskManagementSummaryRemarks remark);

        IEnumerable<string> UpdateRiskManagementSummaryRemarks(Tb_RiskManagementSummaryRemarks remark);

        IEnumerable<string> DeleteRiskManagementSummaryRemarks(Tb_RiskManagementSummaryRemarks remark);

        IEnumerable<string> DeleteRiskManagementSummaryRemarks(Guid recordId);

        IEnumerable<Tb_RiskManagementSummaryRemarks> FetchSummaryRemarks(string acctNo, long companyId, int period = 0);

        #region "RMS details"

        IEnumerable<Tb_CashRPValuationCollateral> FetchValuationCollateral(long companyId, string acctNo = null, string currCd = null, long fundSourceID = 0);

        IEnumerable<Tb_CustodyAssetsRPValuationCollateral> FetchValuationCollateral(long companyId, string acctNo = null, string currCd = null, long fundSourceID = 0, long instrumentId = 0, long productId = 0);

        IEnumerable<Tb_NonEquityAssetsValuationCollateral> FetchValuationCollateral(long companyId, string acctNo = null, string assetNo = null);

        IEnumerable<TmsModel.Tb_Transactions> FetchTMSTransactions(long companyId, string acctNo = null, string transNo = null, string transGroupNo = null, string currCd = null, long fundSourceID = 0);

        IEnumerable<Tb_ContractOutstanding> FetchOutstandingContracts(long companyId, string acctNo = null, string contractNo = null, short contractPartNo = -1, string currCd = null, long fundSourceID = 0);

        IEnumerable<TmsModel.Tb_ContractOutstanding> FetchTMSOutstandingContracts(long companyId, string acctNo = null, string contractNo = null, short contractPartNo = -1, string currCd = null, long fundSourceID = 0);

        IEnumerable<Tb_OrderImport> FetchOrders(long companyId, string acctNo = null, long orderNo = 0, long subOrderNo = -1, string currCd = null);

        IEnumerable<TmsModel.Tb_ContractOutstanding> FetchExecutedOrdersAndTMSContracts(long companyId, string acctNo = null, string currCd = null);

        Tb_Date FetchBusinessDate(long companyId = 0);

        #endregion "RMS details"

    }
}








[LogOperation]
[LogServiceErrors]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class RmsOrchestrationContext : EntityService<IRiskManagementRepository>,  CQGlobal.BackOffice.Service.Types.Contracts.IRmsContract
    {
        public string DoWork(string work)
        {
            //System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Called From Service");
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", work);
        }


 public IEnumerable<RMSDisplay> SearchSummary(string filter,string ordering="AccountNo",int pageNo=0, int pageSize=0)
        {
            try
            {
                using (IRiskManagementRepository repo = new RiskManagementRepository())
                {
                    return repo.FetchRMSSummary(filter, ordering, pageNo, pageSize);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
            }

        }




namespace CQGlobal.BackOffice.Service.Types
{
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    [DataContract(IsReference = true, Namespace = "http://www.cqglobal.com/rms/")]
    [Serializable]
    public class RMSDisplay
    {
        [DataMember]
        public System.DateTime ReportDate { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string RecordType { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string AggregateLevel { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string AcctNo { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public long CompanyId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string CurrCd { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int SchemeId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public decimal ExchRate { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public decimal LedgerBFBalance { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public decimal EquitySettlement { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public decimal Adjustment { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public decimal RealisedPL { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public decimal CommissionCharges { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public decimal OptionPremium { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public decimal LedgerRPBalance { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public decimal CollateralRPBalance { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public decimal UnrealisedPLBalance { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public decimal MarginIM { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public decimal MarginMM { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public decimal MarginIMExcessDeficit { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public decimal MarginIMRPExcessDeficit { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public decimal MarginMMExcessDeficit { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public decimal MarginMMRPExcessDeficit { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public System.DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string AcctExecutiveCd { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public Nullable<System.Guid> RecordId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Topic { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Remarks { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int Page { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int Size { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int TotalCount { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<string> ValidationErrors { get; set; }

        *[DataMember]
        public string ClientName { get; set; }*



        #region IExtensibleDataObject Members

        public ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData { get; set; }

        #endregion IExtensibleDataObject Members
    }
}
```

I wrote my service in visual studio 2010 version. And then I upgraded it into visual studio 2012. When I add properties to my contract the ClientName I got a null value to this property. I already tried put order in the fields still I don't get the value I expected even I hardcoded the value. I also try recycle of the AppPool, restart my pc still has error. Sorry I dont show you the actual implementation of this function  repo.FetchRMSSummary(filter, ordering, pageNo, pageSize). As I traced it in the server side it has a value but when i consume the service I cannot get right value. My property become a nullobject but the rest old properties has the right value.

Please help me.

Comment: Did you update the reference in your client?

Comment: yes I updated my client. I removed the reference and attached reference again with the updated dll

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to override deserialization of your object to debug it. I had similar issue when deserialization was failed.

Comment: Actually this project was developed by someone who left already and now I am the successor of his code. He has a project like      [assembly:System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly:System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerVersionAttribute(ParentAssemblyId=@"128e48f7-e37b-4470-8a30-9c970ac05f15,", Version=@"4.0.0.0")]
namespace Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly {

    public class XmlSerializationWriter1 : System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter {            
 ...... in which this project as I digest is that it gabbles the contract automatically .

Answer (score 0):

I already solved the problem. Actually we made a serializer of the contract so that it could boost the performance of the service and it goes something bad that my client got the old one which is acted weird because it caches to the system.